# Make font height the size of viewport height

Tags: html, css

I want to make a few letters in a  tag to fit the entire height of the browser window, kinda like so http://flavinsky.com/work/suspended-animations (Notice the 04).

But instead of using an svg image I want to use real text.

Is this possible? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css atribute

```
 font-size:100vh;
```

[Learn more](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)

Comment: This doesnt make the letters full browser window height and adds vertical scrollbars which I don't want.